# grouping mongo documents using elements of array field

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have below 3 documents. Each represents a contact for a user :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f9f9f3b91d070315273d0d"), 
    "profileId" : "test", 
    "displayName" : "duplicateTest", 
    "email" : [
        {
            "emailId" : "a@a.com"
        }, 
        {
            "emailId" : "b@b.com"
        }, 
        {
            "emailId" : "c@c.com"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f9fab2b91d070315273d11"), 
    "profileId" : "test", 
    "displayName" : "duplicateTest2", 
    "email" : [
        {
            "emailId" : "a@a.com"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f9fcefb91d070315273d15"), 
    "profileId" : "test", 
    "displayName" : "duplicateTest2", 
    "email" : [
        {
            "emailId" : "b@b.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to aggregate/group them by array elements so that I can identify the duplicate contact ( based on email id). Since there is a common email id between doc (1 & 2) and doc( 1 & 3) these 3 represent one contact and should be merged into one as one contact.

I tried doing this using $unwind and $group in java as below:

```
List<DBObject> aggList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();

        BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("profileId", "0fb72dcf-292b-4343-a0e7-1d613a803b1e"));

        aggList.add(dbo);

        BasicDBObject dboUnwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$email");
        aggList.add(dboUnwind);



        BasicDBObject dboGroup = new BasicDBObject("$group",
                new BasicDBObject().append("_id", new BasicDBObject("name", "$email.emailId"))
                        .append("uniqueIds", new BasicDBObject("$addToSet", "$_id"))
                        .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)));

        aggList.add(dboGroup);

        BasicDBObject dboCount = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("count", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 2)));
        aggList.add(dboCount);


        BasicDBObject dboSort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("count",-1));
        aggList.add(dboSort);


        BasicDBObject dboLimit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 10);
        aggList.add(dboLimit);


        AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(aggList);


    System.out.println(output.results());
```

This groups docs by email id (and rightly so) but doesn't serves the purpose.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I need to implement the feature where user can be prompted about the possible duplicate contacts in his repository. I need aggregation result to be something like:

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":{  
         "name":[  
            {
            "emailId" : "a@a.com"
        }, 
        {
            "emailId" : "b@b.com"
        }, 
        {
            "emailId" : "c@c.com"
        }
         ]
      },
      "uniqueIds":[  
         {  
            "$oid":"57f9fcefb91d070315273d15"
         },
 {  
            "$oid":"57f9fcefb91d070315273d11"
         },
 {  
            "$oid":"57f9fcefb91d070315273d15"
         }
      ],
      "count":3
   },
```

So basically, I need _id  for all possible duplicate contacts (there could be another group of duplicates with _ids list as above) so that I can prompt it to user and user can merge them at his will. 
Hope its more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean by merged into one document? Do you want to delete the duplicate or just identify the duplicate only?

Comment: Please define your purpose clearly, cause when i do the aggregation supplied in your code it works ok. It returns new documents where profiles are merged into 1. With this you could do somekind of clean up or merge. So i am missing what you are missing :)

Comment: @notionquest I need to identify and prompt to user at first. If he chooses to merge that I can do later

Comment: @HoefMeistert I have edited the question. basically i need to identify all dupilcates based on email id. It doesnt works properly because as mentioned above it does not gives 1 document with union of all email ids.

Comment: @HoefMeistert This second solution is not acccurate. It just groups all the contacts by profileId. What I want is for a given profileID (in this case *test*) All contacts where email array has a common email id (directly or transitively)should group. There can obviously be multiple such groups.                      I will try to explain with the help of simple example lets say a user with userid "test1" is logged in. He will have a "find duplicates" button. when he clicks on that he should see the grouping(if you have seen one in gmail (find and merge duplicates option)).

Comment: for example:contact1 { profileid: test1, email: ["a", "b"]}
contact 2: { profileid: test1, email: ["a"]}    
contact 3: { profileid: test1, email: ["b"]}
contact 4: { profileid: test1, email: ["p"]}
contact 5: { profileid: test1, email: ["p", "q"]}
Now since contact 2 & contact 3 dont have direct common email id but each has  a common email id with contact 1 we should prompt to user that contact 1&2&3 are potential duplicates. Also same for contact 4&5.
so output should be something like:

Comment: [{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "emails" : [
       "a", 
       "b", 
     
    ], 
    "duplicates" : [
    1,2,3
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "emails" : [
       “p", 
        “q", 
     
    ], 
    "duplicates" : [
  4,5
    ]
 }

]

Answer (score 0):

Well your question differs a bit from the result you are seeking. Your inital question pointed me to the following aggregation:

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$email"
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$email.emailId",
      duplicates : { $addToSet : "$_id"}
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

This results in:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "c@c.com", 
    "duplicates" : [
        ObjectId("57f9f9f3b91d070315273d0d")
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "b@b.com", 
    "duplicates" : [
        ObjectId("57f9fcefb91d070315273d15"), 
        ObjectId("57f9f9f3b91d070315273d0d")
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "a@a.com", 
    "duplicates" : [
        ObjectId("57f9fab2b91d070315273d11"), 
        ObjectId("57f9f9f3b91d070315273d0d")
    ]
}
```

Grouped by EMail.

But the sample output you added to your question made this aggregation:

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$email"
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$profileId",
      emails : { $addToSet : "$email.emailId"},
      duplicates : { $addToSet : "$_id"}
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Which results in:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "emails" : [
        "c@c.com", 
        "b@b.com", 
        "a@a.com"
    ], 
    "duplicates" : [
        ObjectId("57f9fcefb91d070315273d15"), 
        ObjectId("57f9fab2b91d070315273d11"), 
        ObjectId("57f9f9f3b91d070315273d0d")
    ]
}
```

Comment: This second solution is not acccurate. It just groups all the contacts by profileId. What I want is for a given profileID (in this case *test*) All contacts where email array has a common email id (directly or transitively)should group. There can obviously be multiple such groups.                        
 I will try to explain with the help of simple example
lets say a user with userid "test1" is logged in. He will have a "find duplicates" button. when he clicks on that he should see the grouping(if you have seen one in gmail (find and merge duplicates option)). Example in next comment.

Comment: for example:contact1 { profileid: test1, email: ["a", "b"]}
contact 2: { profileid: test1, email: ["a"]}    
contact 3: { profileid: test1, email: ["b"]}
contact 4: { profileid: test1, email: ["p"]}
contact 5: { profileid: test1, email: ["p", "q"]}
Now since contact 2 & contact 3 dont have direct common email id but each has  a common email id with contact 1 we should prompt to user that contact 1&2&3 are potential duplicates. Also same for contact 4&5.
so output should be something like:

Comment: [{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "emails" : [
       "a", 
       "b", 
     
    ], 
    "duplicates" : [
    1,2,3
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "emails" : [
       “p", 
        “q", 
     
    ], 
    "duplicates" : [
  4,5
    ]
 }

]